# Proving divisibility for $256 \mid 7^{2n} + 208n - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

I can't come up with a way of proving this:

$$256 \mid 7^{2n} + 208n - 1\\ \forall n \in \Bbb N$$

I've tried by induction but couldn't see when to apply the inductive hypothesis...

$$P(n+1) = 7^{2n+2}+208n+207$$

How can I continue?
Thank you

Comment: If you are going to do induction you want $7^{2n+2} + 208(n+1) - 1 = 7^{2n} + 208n - 1 + 256K$.  We can do $7^{2n + 2} + 208(n+1)-1 = 7^{2n}*49 + 208n - 1 + 208 = 7^{2n} + 208n - 1 + (48*7^{2n} + 208)$ and $48*7^{2n} + 208 = 16(3*7^{2n} + 13)$ suffices to show $16|3*7^{2n} + 13$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inductive hypothesis $7^{2n}+208n-1=256m$, $m\in \mathbb{N}$

Therefore $7^{2n+2}+208n+207=49(256m+1-208n)+208n+207=49\cdot256m-48\cdot208n+256=49\cdot256m-39\cdot256n+256=256(49m-39n+1)$ is divisible by $256$.

Answer (score 4):

By the binomial theorem, $7^{2n}=49^n=(48+1)^n=48^2a+48n+1$ and so $$7^{2n} + 208n - 1 = 48^2a+256n = 256(9a+n)$$

Comment: This argument explains where $208n$ comes from:$208=256-48$.

Comment: It's even more straightforward using modular arithmetic - see my answer where only simple mental arithmetic is used.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 16^2\!:\ 7^{2n} \equiv\, 48n+1\,\ $ [i.e. $\,P(n)$], $\,$ when multiplied by $\,7^2$

implies $\,$ that $\ \ 7^{2(n+1)}\equiv \color{#0a0}{7^2}(\color{#0a0}{48}n+1)\equiv \color{#c00}{48}n\!+\!49 = 48(n\!+\!1)+1\,\ $ [i.e. $P(n\!+\!1)$]

because $\,\ \color{#0a0}{7^2(48)} = (1+3\!\cdot\! 16)(3\!\cdot\!16)\equiv \color{#c00}{48}\ $ by $\ 16^2\equiv 0\,\ $ using only mental arithmetic!

Comment: We used: $\ $ mod $ \, 16^2\!:\ \ {-}208\equiv 16^2\!-208\equiv \color{#c00}{48}\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

We have transforming step by step suitably,
$$7^{2n}+208n-1=$$
$$(48+1)^n+(256-48)n-1=$$
$$(2^4\cdot3+1)^n+(256-2^4\cdot3)n-1 =$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{k=n-1}\binom nk (2^4\cdot3)^{n-k}+1+256n-2^4\cdot3n-1=$$ 
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{k=n-2}\binom nk (2^4\cdot3)^{n-k}+256n+2^4\cdot3n-2^4\cdot3n=$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{k=n-2}\binom nk (2^4\cdot3)^{n-k}+256n\equiv 0\pmod{256}$$